# Display date label on tableview scroll like whatsapp

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, whatsapp

Hello I just want to show the date **Today** label when the UITableView is scrolled as we have in whatsapp. [Whatsapp Video Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10Cf.jpg).

Also If we start scrolling the yesterday's chat, we can see the label of **yesterday** in whatsapp & automatically hides when scrolling of tableview is stopped. If it is possible with/without sections of the tableview.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Add date label in section in TableView . First make date in descending order, On the basis of that you can group data and fetch data.

Comment: Is there any way without using section??

Comment: As per flexibility and easy way to do in tableView  is with section only. If I get any other reference, will inform you.

Answer (score 2):

**I think, You are looking for like this-**

[image]

**To achieve this-**

```
let uiScreen = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
let whatsAppTableView = UITableView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.customization()
        whatsAppTableView.dataSource = self
        whatsAppTableView.delegate = self
        whatsAppTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "w") //w = whatsapp background Image
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
        self.whatsAppTableView.backgroundView = imageView
        whatsAppTableView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:uiScreen.width, height: uiScreen.height)
        whatsAppTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        view.addSubview(whatsAppTableView)

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0 {
            return 3
        }
        if section == 1 {
            return 3
        }
        if section == 2 {
            return 5
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerLabelView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: whatsAppTableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (whatsAppTableView.frame.size.width-100)/2, y: 20, width: 100, height: 40))

        headerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        headerLabel.font = AppFont.PopinsBold(size: 12)
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        headerLabel.roundedAllCorner()
        //headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        if section == 0 {
            headerLabel.text = "5 December" // Put it dynamic as requirment  [Date Array]
        }
        if section == 1 {
            headerLabel.text = "Yesterday"
        }
        if section == 2 {
            headerLabel.text =  "Today"
        }

        headerLabelView.addSubview(headerLabel)
        return headerLabelView
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3 // Depends on your date array
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300 //Put As you required
    }
```

**To check scroll direction/position-**

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if(velocity.y>0) {
            //Code will work without the animation block.I am using animation block incase if you want to set any delay to it.
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {

                print("Hide")
            }, completion: nil)

        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {


                print("Unhide")
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question , I want to use without section

Comment: Then you can use the first row of tableView for your cell to display date, But as my experience, it will be better to use with section

Comment: I also want to hide/show the section(if used) when the tableview scrolls stop/start the scrolling .. Is it possible with sections?

Comment: I think yes. You can get scroll position/direction to show/hide section, Check my updated code to get the scroll direction.

Comment: I cannot see the updated code!!!

Comment: check now please

Comment: I want hide/show the section of tableview not the navigation bar.. Is it possible with the sections?

Answer (score 1):

Some advice:

1. Observe UITableView scrolling start and stop

   Maybe you can observe tableview scroll via implement UIScrollViewDelegate. There are two methods to tell delegate scroll view is about start/stop scrolling the content.
   `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, `scrollViewWillEndDragging`
2. Show lable not via tableview section

   Just add your **Today** label as UITableView's subview

Comment: And how to detect that cells of chat are showing of yesterday or today?

Comment: @Dimple how about tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview), Tells the delegate the table view is about to draw a cell for a particular row. You can know which cell will become visible or invisible.